# How do you change a line of code in a specific file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example, I have multiple node_modules and one of the files needs to be modified in order to work.

Example in /path/to/file.js:

```
Import {something,somethingElse} from “something”
```

Needs to be:

```
Import {something} from “something”
```

I know about grep, sed but I don’t know which is best for this.

Comment: open in an editor and update it?

Comment: @Alex that’s fine for a one time thing, for you and only you. That’s not enough if you’re software depends on the patch and other developers unfamiliar with the work around need to install 3rd party software and apply the patch. The purpose of having a bash script or a command-line solution is remove bottlenecks in software development in distributed teams while a long term solution can be planned. In this case we may end up forking the package and republishing it because it’s unmaintained and required on all future and present projects.

Comment: I wonder if there's a cleaner solution, where you avoid touching your dependency and instead try to work around it... could you share the error that occurs because of this line you want to change?

Comment: @Gershy it's defiantly a last resort. Someone on the team already submitted a PR months ago and there are multiple issues open on it. In fact that's how we found out what file to change and how to change it. But I'd rather not browser through node_modules and change it every time we use the package.

Comment: Whether it's the answer to the question you _wanted_ to ask, Alex's comment is the answer to the question you've actually typed here. If there are some more details to the situation regarding automation, package creation, etc, then you need to [edit] the question and say what those are; otherwise, it's all just a guessing game of "if you're trying to achieve this, use this; or maybe you wanted that..."

Comment: Also this question is not node.js or javascript related.
You should update your tags.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` checks for matches in a file. `sed` is a stream editor. What you can do is locate the file containing a string (or line of code) using `grep`, then stream (or pipe) the file through `sed` to create a new (updated) file, then overwrite the old file.

From the top of my head:

```
STRING="Import {something,somethingElse} from “something”"
REPLACE="Import {something} from “something”"

MATCHING_FILES=$(grep -r $(DIR) -e "$STRING" -l)
OUTPUT=`mktemp`

for file in "$MATCHING_FILES"; do
    cat $file | sed -e "s/$STRING/$REPLACE/g" > $OUTPUT
    cp $OUTPUT $file
done
```

For a single file, you can omit the `grep` step as you know its path:

```
STRING="Import {something,somethingElse} from “something”"
REPLACE="Import {something} from “something”"

OUTPUT=`mktemp`

cat $YOUR_FILE | sed -e "s/$STRING/$REPLACE/g" > $OUTPUT
cp $OUTPUT $YOUR_FILE
```

Comment: I think that should work. I can store that in a bash file and then just run the bash file right? If so, I could add a postinstall script and run it.

Comment: Yes you could easily do this. Try it first though, I did this real fast and might have left stuff out. Also, `mktemp` may not work in certain environments. All it does is give you a filename in `/tmp`.

Comment: @sproutnik wait, I'm getting "grep: warning recursive search..."

also how to I configure the path to the file?
Example: `./node_modules/@react-something/something/lib/module/views/something.js`
I used `MATCHING_FILES=$(grep -r $(DIR config/something.js) -e "$STRING" -l)`
I get most of that, but I don't understand what the matching_files script is doing as well as I thought.

Comment: Okay so what the `grep` here did was to recursively search a directory for matching files. If you know what file you need to change the line in, the process is much simpler: ```STRING="Import {something,somethingElse} from “something”"
REPLACE="Import {something} from “something”"

OUTPUT=`mktemp`

cat $YOUR_FILE | sed -e "s/$STRING/$REPLACE/g" > $OUTPUT; cp $OUTPUT $file ```